# I can not DELETE git repository with API in Python

Tags: python, api, github-api

I am using github api with oauth in python, I have created repositories successfully, but now I am trying to delete them and I always get 404 code.

```
import requests
import pprint


if __name__=='__main__':
    url = "https://api.github.com/user/repos/albinr3/repositorio-de-prueba3" #I added manually the complete url just for test
    #repo='repositorio-de-prueba3'
    #owner='/albinr3/'
    headers = {'Accept':'application/vnd.github.v3+json', "Authorization": "token {tokenumber}"}
    
    response = requests.delete(url, headers=headers )
    print(response.url)
    if response.status_code == 204:
        pprint.pprint(response.json())
    else:
        pprint.pprint(response.status_code)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, the problem was the URL, I was using the same URL that is used to create a repository: `https://api.github.com/user/repos` but the URL to `DELETE` a repository is: `https://api.github.com/repos/` (without "user"), that was the problem.